# Is there a way to have two or more clipboards via keyboard shortcuts for storing & using multiple text items simultaneously? (OSX)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, applescript

I would like to be able to have multiple clipboards on Mac OSX (happen to be using Mavericks currently). The end-solution would look something like this:

Let's say I copied one piece of text using...

1. <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C/kbd> to copy and <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V/kbd> to paste like normal.</kbd></kbd>

...But then I could also do...

2. <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste other text without overwriting A's text.

Maybe in another implementation I could add a third clipboard by using <kbd>⌘cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧shift</kbd>+⌥alt+C, and so on. The keyboard shortcuts themselves are not important, nor is the number of additional clipboards.

Does anything like this exist? If not, how difficult would it be for an amateur programmer to implement on OSX using something like AppleScript or, god be praised, ruby/python, etc?

Would definitely prefer not having to code this on my own of course, but that's always an option for a weekend open-source warrior project...I could definitely make a valiant effort at least...

EDIT: I see there are clipboard buffers, and I know a lot of popular text editors like emacs and textmate have clipboard buffers, but I guess to differentiate myself here I'm looking for a solution that uses dedicated keyboard shortcuts to access buffer_elements[1..n], respectively, where n equals 1-2 (3 clipboards) maybe...I'm thinking now that I could potentially register new keyboard shortcuts to access a clipboard buffer via shell script and maybe have those dumped into a selected text area using AppleScript or something...that might work...

Comment: Having found the opensource tool jumpcut on this superuser thread (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15867/how-can-i-copy-and-paste-multiple-texts) I'm thinking I should close this question. I will do so in a couple of hours unless someone thinks I should keep this question up due to its marginal unique-ness.

Comment: I used to have an app to do this like 15 years ago, under Mac OS 9 (lol!). I think the current version of this app is this: http://plumamazing.com/mac/copypaste

Answer (score 1):

I use [clip menu](http://www.clipmenu.com/)
BTW this is mac only

you press cmd +shft + V and the menu comes up at your mouse showing the last 10 copies, this number can be changed, I have mine set at 1000

[image: example of clip menu pic]